# How do I estimate the radial distortion parameters for a given image?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, octave, distortion

I have found the camera matrix for an image using DLT :

```
P =

  3.8618e-03   7.1665e-04   1.9713e-03  -9.1510e-01
  3.1222e-05   4.4639e-03  -7.6783e-04  -4.0317e-01
 -5.9516e-07   1.1950e-06   1.7221e-06  -1.0115e-03
```

How do I proceed to find the radial distortion parameters.

Tools: OpenCV/Octave

Comment: Can you tell us, what have you done till now?

Comment: Using DLT, I have found the camera matrix. I look forward to find the radial distortion parameters.

Comment: I suggest a read on `undistortImage` which when combined with `cameraParameters` should solve your problem for you. Also read the example carefully. http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/undistortimage.html

Comment: As for OpenCV give a look to this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to calibrate your camera. For that you would need to take multiple images of a planar calibration pattern, e. g. a checkerboard.

If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB, you can use the [Camera Calibrator app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html).